# What's best shape for linear concentrated solar panel?

Tags: reflection

I found 3 shapes which are suitable for concentrated solar panel.
1. **Semicircle** - first thing that comes to ones mind.
It's a simple shape, the position of the focal point is obvious.
2. **Parabolic mirror**
A bit more difficult shape.
[image: Parabolic mirror]
3. **Compound parabolic mirror**
[image: Compound Parabolic mirror]
Compound parabolic mirror has an advantage over the parabolic mirror in acceptance angle. Collector doesn't necessarily need to track sun, because it's able to receive sunlight from a range of angles.

**Is there any other shape, that might have interesting properties for the purpose of solar collector?**
I found many DIY designs with semicircle mirrors. And many scientific papers with parabolic mirrors.
 **What is the advantage of parabolic mirrors are over semicircle mirrors?**

Comment: Compute the optimal radius and curvature for your required diameter and distance. If they are similar, go for the semicircle because it is easier to manufacture.

Comment: Note that engineering-type questions of the sort "what is the best way to build [...]", that involve trade-offs between different factors that depend on specific application, are not really something we can help with. Your final question, "what are possible advantages of X over Y?" is something amenable to physics arguments and something we can help with, but you should really rephrase your whole question on that gear. Otherwise, this question may be closed. See [this meta post](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/4535/) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You've identified the classic shapes.  There is no "magic shape" that outperforms these in all situations.

You need to consider the *weather* conditions if you are designing for a practical installation:

1. Sunny days only
2. Cloudy days and sunny days

In addition, you need to consider:

1. Sun's movement over the span of the day
2. Sun's movement over the seasons

You say it does not need to track the sun.  This is generally not true.  A parabolic trough will not work equally well with and without tracking.  The sun does not move in a "straight line" because that line moves with the seasons.

Solar concentration must also consider the heat load on the photovoltaic cell.  Photovoltaics are not 100% efficient in the visible band and there is also a lot of energy outside the visible (e.g. NIR) that adds to the heat load on the photovoltaic.  *Conversion to electricity goes down with increases in temperature.*  As the concentration increases, the problem gets quite severe.

Comment: I didn't mention it's not PV solar panel. It's water heating system with evacuated tube as receiver. It will be designed as all season panel, so it'll be tilted towards "winter sun" and it'll track day movement of sun. If there's no magic shape I'm in search for, :) which is better semicircle, or parabolic shape? And why?

Comment: Sorry...didn't see the semi-circle.  That's really not very useful.  The parabola and CPC are recognized as the best.  You may be able to get better, but I haven't seen it yet.